# how to thin bitumin base coating

Tags: chassis-paint

I have "OEM brushable rubberized bitumin based undercoating."

"Dominion sure seal"

It says "contains mineral spirits". It says "up to 3.75 e2 gram/ litre"

I understand it may be an emulsion if I add thinner.

Is there some real reason I can't add solvent to get a paintable batch?

Comment: "Brushable" means paintable ...

Comment: @SolarMike - I think he's trying to thin it ... To the OP: If the undercoating uses mineral spirits as it's base, you should be able to use it to thin it out. You can always take a very small portion and try it out. Nothing to lose but a bit of product.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 usually products like that are thick for a reason - the title does say it is brushable... thinning it may well reduce it's protection properties if is is then too thin a coat.

Comment: Being undercoating, I suspect it's thick so that it doesn't drip down as readily as a thinner product may.  As long as you're ok with some additional dripping, I don't think thinning with mineral spirits will adversely impact the product performance as the spirits will evaporate for the most part and the product will set as intended.

Comment: @SolarMike - Oh, I agree with you wholeheartedly.